# Adding to selection within a loop using JSON

Tags: jquery, json, dictionary, append

I'm attempting to map JSON to a specific HTML structure. I'd like to loop over the JSON, create a jQuery object containing the structure it should have, then add it to a collection that was initiated earlier.

I'm testing the length of the JSON before hand, and the length of the collection afterwards, but the collection is coming out at 0. I can't understand why the `add()` method isn't working for me here.

I've also tried using `map()` to get my collection, but to no avail.

**Example JSON**

```
var d = [
    {"NOTICE_ID":"23","TITLE":"fw4r4","BODY":"34t35t","CREATED_BY":"George","TIMESTAMP":"1400856243.1416"},
    {"NOTICE_ID":"22","TITLE":"op","BODY":"op","CREATED_BY":"George","TIMESTAMP":"1400854953.8122"}
]
```

**jQuery**

```
console.log(d.length)

$sections = $([]);
$.each(d, function(){
    var $sect = $('<section id="notice-'+this['NOTICE_ID']+'" class="type-1" data-time="'+this["TIMESTAMP"]+'"></section>'),
        $head = $("<h2>"+this["TITLE"]+"</h2>").appendTo($sect),
        $date = $("<span>"+this["TIMESTAMP"]+"</span>").appendTo($head),
        $body = $("<div>"+this["BODY"]+"</div>").appendTo($sect);
    $sections.add($sect);
});

console.log($sections.length);
```

I would expect `$sections.length` to be the same as `d.length`, but it is always 0.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T4N4f/2/)

My aim is to eventually sort the sections and then append them to a container as one. It works fine if I append each element from within the loop:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T4N4f/1/)

Why am I not able to add to my empty jQuery Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with [**`$.merge()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/):

```
$.merge($sections,$sect);
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/HGQ9V/**

Comment: @oGeez Yeah, I was surprised when I found out. I'm glad it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

Just set up $sections as a standard javascript array and use push() to add the new elements to it:

```
$sections = new Array();
.
.
.
$sections.push($sect);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T4N4f/3/

Comment: But that will just be a standard array of jQuery objects. I want a jQuery object for all sections.

Comment: All of the sections ARE jQuery objects, they are just being held in an array.

Comment: I get that. But I can't call jQuery methods on `$sections` because it is an array.

Comment: What methods would you want to be calling on it? Or to ask another way, what aren't you able to do with an array that you'd be able to do if it was a jQuery object?

Comment: That's beside the point. The question was how to get all of the jQuery objects created in the loop, in one jQuery object. Thanks though.